# GitHub pages and jekyll deploy not working properly

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

My `jekyll` blog is running ok in my pc but when I open it from my gh repository it's broken. Here's a screen of that

[image]

If I click on one of the links, that next page throws `404`. Needless to say, I followed the steps from the gh site in order to configure it properly.

`baseurl` is set, the paths to `css` and `images` are correctly set using `{{ site.baseurl }}`. So locally the blog works fine, but still, on `gh-pages` it's not.

Code is [here](https://github.com/goblind/modestoRimba)

Another piece of information. I have a `master` branch and a `gh-pages` branch, the one updated is `gh-pages`, master has old code, is it ok?

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

It works ! What you saw was an old version of your site.

Two possible explanations :

- as @goyllo says : browser cache `f5` or `Ctrl+r` can help.
- Github pages is serving the old version and the new site generation is still pending.

In order to know if you last commit has been published it to go to https://github.com/goblind/modestoRimba/settings and to watch under **GitHub Pages** box.

If you see `Your site is ready to be published at http://goblind.github.io/modestoRimba`, your site generation is pending.

If you see  `Your site is published at http://goblind.github.io/modestoRimba`, your site have been published with last commit.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine in my browser. I want to say one thing, GitHub pages cache your old resources(including HTML, CSS, JS, Images), in browser for better UX, For example, just disconnect your internet, and reload that page again, and it will be work fine, similarly if you visit another page, then it will not load your CSS, or javascript again from your website, they will load directly from **browser cache.** So you are getting this error because your browser use old cache resource, and it will update again in few hour, depending on cache time.

I want to say, if your blog working fine in localhost, then don't worry, it will be also work fine in github pages as well, otherwise github will send you notice in your email regarding page build fail.

Answer (score 0):

in your _config.yml baseurl: /modesto**r**imba **R** should be uppercase.